# Filtering a list with date ranges - xslt / advanced expressions on list filters possible?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, xslt, filter

I've got a Sharepoint 2010 list that I'd like to filter with date-ranges. I'm doing something like

```
if END_DATE > [NOW - 1Week]
and END_DATE < [NOW + 1Week]
or PLAN_END > [NOW -1Week]
and PLAN_END < [NOW +1Week]
```

I will post the real code at the end of this post, but as it's just a bunch of code, it doesn't have too much of real relevance.

Now, when I use conditional formatting, I can use advanced expressions to make that happen (expression see below), but when using the list-view-webpart on a webpart-page - the additional formatting gets lost, which is intended behavior as I recall.

So I do not only have to hide the entries I dont want to see, I just do not have to select them in the first place (which makes more sense anyways). But is this possible via List-Filters? I know I can edit the code and write some XML-LINQ-Like expressions (forgive my terminology, really new to all this), but I can't find out how I would write the expression I need.

To sum it up: How can I FILTER a list with Date-Ranges?

And here the actual conditional formatting that I do (Hide all, where condition is not met)

```
not((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Plan_x0020_Ende))) >= (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:Today())-(7*24*60*60*1000*10000))) 
    and (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Plan_x0020_Ende))) <= (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:Today())+(7*24*60*60*1000*10000)))) 
and not((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Ist_x0020_Ende))) >= (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:Today())-(7*24*60*60*1000*10000))) 
    and (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Ist_x0020_Ende))) <= (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:Today())+(7*24*60*60*1000*10000))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter list by using CAML and **DaysOffset** attribute of the **Today** tag. This can be done even from GUI.

For example, this filter will narrow the shown items of a list view to those, which have Due date within a week from the current date:

[image]

(*List Tools => List => Modify view* on the contextual ribbon)

In terms of CAML, this will produce the following query:

```
<Query>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
    </OrderBy>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Gt>
                <FieldRef Name="DueDate"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today OffsetDays="-7"/>
                </Value>
            </Gt>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name="DueDate"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today OffsetDays="7"/>
                </Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

And btw, cannot resist mentioning, that the XSLT filtering approach is very expensive in case of resources (especially if there are **many** items in the list), and gives up the list paging. Personally, I would never ever use it in any case...

Comment: Great, thank you! This CAML_Statement is exactly what i needed - seeing this i begin to understand how this lines up :) This helps a great deal. Thank you! Far easier to write, too :P

Comment: Writing XSL to solve specific requirements can be a great idea. You need to understand the tradeoffs, as you do with any programming. Ylou don't give up paging per se; DVWPs can also have paging.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson, I meant, when you have XSLT filtering, you will either get unpredictable number of items per page, or you will have to give up the paging. Myself I'm a great fan of XSLT and XsltListViewWebPart and I'm dealing with complex XSL transformations almost every day. I definitely admire its capabilities, but it is still not a silver bullet, and I wouldn't use it for filtering or sorting.